# Protobuf with .Net 4.8 - Compilation complains about missing classes

Tags: c#, msbuild, protocol-buffers, grpc, .net-4.8

I need to use protobuf with a C# .Net 4.8 project (as client).
I added the following Nuget packages including all dependencies

- Google.Protobuf 3.25.2
- Grpc 2.46.6
- Grpc.Tools 2.60.0

I added the .proto file to the project and set build action to "Protobuf" which added an entry to the .csproj file
`<Protobuf Include="CorrectPathToFile.proto" />`

Visual Studio correctly generated 2 C# files within the obj folder. And Intellisense sees the generated classes.

Now the problem: The compiler doesnt. It complains the classes that Intellisense sees are missing

EDIT:

[The .csproj file](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/pg7a66pb4jlagvgk1qs3h/PlanetAI.csproj?rlkey=k8rt4fdalyh3olu0n37uopwj0&dl=0)

I am not sure if I can provide the .proto file for legal reasons. But I have another project that is .NET 6 and there everything works fine with the same file.

Here the VS2022 error messages

```
Fehler  CS0246  Der Typ- oder Namespacename "ProcessImage" wurde nicht gefunden (möglicherweise fehlt eine using-Direktive oder ein Assemblyverweis).   PlanetAI    C:\Dev\3.2\Feeder\PlanetAI\PlanetAI\PlanetAIClassification\PlanetAIClassificationModule.cs  7   Aktiv
Fehler  CS0246  Der Typ- oder Namespacename "ProcessImageRequest" wurde nicht gefunden (möglicherweise fehlt eine using-Direktive oder ein Assemblyverweis).    PlanetAI    C:\Dev\3.2\Feeder\PlanetAI\PlanetAI\PlanetAIClassification\PlanetAIClassificationModule.cs  62  Aktiv
Fehler  CS0246  Der Typ- oder Namespacename "ProcessImageRequest" wurde nicht gefunden (möglicherweise fehlt eine using-Direktive oder ein Assemblyverweis).    PlanetAI    C:\Dev\3.2\Feeder\PlanetAI\PlanetAI\PlanetAIClassification\PlanetAIClassificationModule.cs  62  Aktiv
Fehler  CS0246  Der Typ- oder Namespacename "ProcessImageResponse" wurde nicht gefunden (möglicherweise fehlt eine using-Direktive oder ein Assemblyverweis).   PlanetAI    C:\Dev\3.2\Feeder\PlanetAI\PlanetAI\PlanetAIClassification\PlanetAIClassificationModule.cs  54  Aktiv
Fehler  CS0246  Der Typ- oder Namespacename "ProcessImageResponse" wurde nicht gefunden (möglicherweise fehlt eine using-Direktive oder ein Assemblyverweis).   PlanetAI    C:\Dev\3.2\Feeder\PlanetAI\PlanetAI\PlanetAIClassification\PlanetAIClassificationModule.cs  68  Aktiv
Fehler  CS0246  Der Typ- oder Namespacename "ProcessImageResponse" wurde nicht gefunden (möglicherweise fehlt eine using-Direktive oder ein Assemblyverweis).   PlanetAI    C:\Dev\3.2\Feeder\PlanetAI\PlanetAI\PlanetAIClassification\PlanetAIClassificationModule.cs  46  Aktiv
Fehler  CS0246  Der Typ- oder Namespacename "ProcessImageV2" wurde nicht gefunden (möglicherweise fehlt eine using-Direktive oder ein Assemblyverweis). PlanetAI    C:\Dev\3.2\Feeder\PlanetAI\PlanetAI\PlanetAIClassification\PlanetAIClassificationModule.cs  54  Aktiv
Fehler  CS0246  Der Typ- oder Namespacename "ProcessImageV2" wurde nicht gefunden (möglicherweise fehlt eine using-Direktive oder ein Assemblyverweis). PlanetAI    C:\Dev\3.2\Feeder\PlanetAI\PlanetAI\PlanetAIClassification\PlanetAIClassificationModule.cs  39  Aktiv
Fehler  CS0246  Der Typ- oder Namespacename "ProcessImageV2" wurde nicht gefunden (möglicherweise fehlt eine using-Direktive oder ein Assemblyverweis). PlanetAI    C:\Dev\3.2\Feeder\PlanetAI\PlanetAI\PlanetAIClassification\PlanetAIClassificationModule.cs  39  Aktiv
Fehler  CS0246  Der Typ- oder Namespacename "ProcessOutputString" wurde nicht gefunden (möglicherweise fehlt eine using-Direktive oder ein Assemblyverweis).    PlanetAI    C:\Dev\3.2\Feeder\PlanetAI\PlanetAI\PlanetAIClassification\PlanetAIClassificationModule.cs  72  Aktiv
Fehler  CS0246  Der Typ- oder Namespacename "RoutingSheetLabelsList" wurde nicht gefunden (möglicherweise fehlt eine using-Direktive oder ein Assemblyverweis). PlanetAI    C:\Dev\3.2\Feeder\PlanetAI\PlanetAI\PlanetAIClassification\PlanetAIClassificationModule.cs  19  Aktiv
Fehler  CS0246  Der Typ- oder Namespacename "RoutingSheetLabelsList" wurde nicht gefunden (möglicherweise fehlt eine using-Direktive oder ein Assemblyverweis). PlanetAI    C:\Dev\3.2\Feeder\PlanetAI\PlanetAI\PlanetAIClassification\PlanetAIClassificationModule.cs  29  Aktiv
Fehler  IDE1100 Fehler beim Lesen des Inhalts der Quelldatei "C:\Dev\3.2\Feeder\PlanetAI\PlanetAI\obj\Debug\PlanetAIClassification\Proto\ProtobufProcessImageV2.cs": "Die Datei "C:\Dev\3.2\Feeder\PlanetAI\PlanetAI\obj\Debug\PlanetAIClassification\Proto\ProtobufProcessImageV2.cs" konnte nicht gefunden werden.".  PlanetAI    C:\Dev\3.2\Feeder\PlanetAI\PlanetAI\obj\Debug\PlanetAIClassification\Proto\ProtobufProcessImageV2.cs    1   Aktiv
Fehler  IDE1100 Fehler beim Lesen des Inhalts der Quelldatei "C:\Dev\3.2\Feeder\PlanetAI\PlanetAI\obj\Debug\PlanetAIClassification\Proto\ProtobufProcessImageV2Grpc.cs": "Die Datei "C:\Dev\3.2\Feeder\PlanetAI\PlanetAI\obj\Debug\PlanetAIClassification\Proto\ProtobufProcessImageV2Grpc.cs" konnte nicht gefunden werden.".  PlanetAI    C:\Dev\3.2\Feeder\PlanetAI\PlanetAI\obj\Debug\PlanetAIClassification\Proto\ProtobufProcessImageV2Grpc.cs    1   Aktiv
```

Comment: You need to add more detail, such as the error messages you see, example csproj and proto files.

Comment: I added what I was able to

Comment: Try playing around with some of the tags of the Protobuf of the .csproj file, like the ProtoRoot tag: `<Protobuf Include="CorrectPathToFile.proto" ProtoRoot="Proto\"/>`. Maybe you just have a relativ path wrong. Its also possible to paste a link with a relative path within it: `<Link>Proto\CorrectPathToFile.proto</Link>`

Comment: Some basic troubleshooting steps: confirm that relative to the location of the project file the `..\packages\Grpc.Tools.2.60.0\build\` and `..\packages\Grpc.Core.2.46.6\build\net45\` directories exist. The project file has `Import`s that depend on these directories. `..\packages\Grpc.Tools.2.60.0\build\Grpc.Tools.props` is imported twice which doesn't look right. Run your project file through the `/preprocess` switch and check the output to see what consumes the `Protobuf` item collection and when.